# One word for "Create a Container"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any single word for "create a container"?
Or even "lay a foundation", "prepare the ground"?

Comment: There seem to be some very different requests here, Meenohara (though metaphorically, they're not irreconcilable). Could you give an example sentence with a space where the envisaged verb would fit? // If it fits, I'll give the answer 'anticipate' (as in 'In his book Matter and Memory of 1896, Bergson anticipated the quantum conception of matter').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am designing my oracle deck for which I needed a word which means preparing for a beginning, having a prepared ground or having an empty cup that is possible to fill. I have already received my answer, but open for more words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Initialize](https://www.google.com/search?q=initialize&rlz=1C1CHBD_enID853ID857&oq=initialize&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4j69i60.1804j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
set to the value or put in the condition appropriate to the start of an operation.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful although quite tech-y. After seeing the word you suggested I was thinking "reset" or "reboot" may be appropriate for my purpose. Still looking for synonyms, but you just gave me what I was looking for.